# Getting from Edinburgh Airport to Linlithgow with lots of luggage

Tags: luggage, transportation, scotland, edinburgh, edi

I wonder what the options are for going from Edinburgh Airport to Linlithgow with lots of luggage? (Two persons with two bags each. Maybe "normal" luggage for most people but I normally travel light.)

There are buses - it is possible to use them with lots of luggage? Otherwise how pricey are cabs in Scotland?

Comment: http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Edinburgh-Airport-EDI/Linlithgow

Comment: http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g186525-i108-k5854310-Edinburgh_Airport_to_Linlithgow-Edinburgh_Scotland.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with Edinburgh is despite having a taxi rank, it's not outside the terminal (that area is reserved for buses).  Since you are presumably arriving from Sweden, it will be a longer walk than from the domestic terminal.  It's not a *ponderous* distance, but something to consider if you are carrying lots of luggage because getting to the taxi rank is something you have to do unassisted.

**Private car service versus taxi**

Taxis are normally a saloon car which will be fine for two people + 4 suitcases. The taxi fare will generally be cheaper.  The downside is that cabbies assemble at the rank when they know there will be lots of arrivals, so if your plane is delayed or you spend a long time claiming your luggage, the rank may be empty and you will need to join a waiting queue.  I got an indicative estimate from a black cab service of GBP 35 Edinburgh to Linlithgow city centre.

The private car service will have the driver holding a courtesy placard with your name on it (normally at the 'meet and greet' point). He may help with the luggage.

Contributor [Patricia Shanahan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19560/patricia-shanahan) has commented...

> On delay causing a private car service to abandon a commission: I
>   don't have experience at Edinburgh, but I have used private car
>   service at several other airports. In each case, the service asked for
>   the flight number and monitored the live flight information. They
>   routinely adjusted their pickup time based on that, accommodating even
>   multi-hour delays.

I got an indicative estimate of GBP 45 for a private car taking you from  Edinburgh to Linlithgow city centre.

In both cases you can book by phone, or email, or an app.  Almost all the major private cab and regulated cab services in the UK have downloadable apps for mobiles and iPads; and a few even have a toll free number.

There are also unregulated drivers who may approach you at the terminal exit. Pricing is done by haggling with them, but they will invariably be cheaper than a regulated driver.  'Caveat emptor' applies.

For your question about buses, buses leaving from the airport are fitted with a purpose built luggage area.  I do not see a problem for two people + 4 suitcases unless somebody gets on before you with a half-dozen steamer trunks. I got an indicative estimate of GBP 6 Edinburgh to Linlithgow High Street.

There are also helicopter services out of Edinburgh Airport, but you have to walk to their mooring zone, and it's farther than walking to the taxi rank.  It's the quickest way (and the priciest way), but you will need a local taxi from their drop off point in Linlithgow.

Comment: For the haggling, there may also be the problem of not even Scot's understand other Scots :)

Comment: On delay causing a private car service to abandon a commission: I don't have experience at Edinburgh, but I have used private car service at several other airports. In each case, the service asked for the flight number and monitored the live flight information. They routinely adjusted their pickup time based on that, accommodating even multi-hour delays.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, good comment, please make it an answer or give permission for me to edit this answer.

Comment: @GayotFow Please do edit it into your answer. I think it will be more useful there than as a separate answer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes every taxi company in the UK does that---otherwise you just waste your drivers' time or upset your customers

Answer (score 3):

An easy option is the tram and a train. The tram stops just in front of the airport, with departures every 10 minutes. Take the tram to Edinburgh Park station, where you can change onto the train. There are trains to Linlithgow about every 30 minutes.

Both the trams and train should have plenty of space for luggage, though the train could get a bit crowded in the rush hour.

Cost about £5 for the tram, plus £5 for the train.

Note there is currently major works on the railway line between Edinburgh and Linlithgow, see [Winchburgh Tunnel engineering works](http://www.scotrail.co.uk/winchburgh) (due to be completed by 26 July). So this means most trains are diverted or replaced by buses. You could still do this journey, but it will take longer and may be busy, so maybe not recommended during this time.

Comment: cool thx (going in late august so should be fine) - can you buy tickets as you go or should it be prebooked?

Comment: No need to book. Just buy a ticket from the ticket machine at the tram stop or station.